# Avoiding memory full -> swap full -> crash

Tags: linux, php, web-server, memory, server-crashes

I'm experiencing an issue when sometimes the memory gets 100% full, and the swap file also, and the server becomes non-responsive and has to be restarted (causing also problems in database). This is what Cacti shows:

[image: Physical Memory]
[image: Swap File]

The server is running a web-app (database + apache) and during that specific moment didn't experience any ir-regular traffic or usage. This scenario happened twice in the last week. What can cause this? How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: I would suggest you have a cron job send you outputs of ps aux, cat /proc/slabinfo etc. every minute or so, either to an email address or to sync-mounted storage. This should make it easy to see what process ran amuck after a crash. If you want to gain time, it might help to increase swap space (you can use a regular file as swap too, just loopback mount it!).

Comment: @rackandboneman: Loopback mount swap file? Aieee! Don't do that. Just `dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/your/swapfile bs=1024 count=1048576` or so and then `mkswap /path/to/your/yourswapfile`. Then `swapon /path/to/your/swapfile` should work.

Comment: If it works, all the better - I did not want to assume it will work on every linux system the TO could have (no version info given), since as per the docs a device file is expected for swapon.

Comment: If you can log in interactively, you could also run top (press shift-m once it's running to sort processes by memory consumption). When the server stops responding, the top display will freeze, so you can examine it at your leisure.

Answer (score -2):

you can clear a cache of linux machine and pu it into a crontab entry to run in regular interval.

Comment: How would you do this? Can you add that to your answer?